# What logical fallacy or cognitive bias is in this statement?

Tags: terminology, logic

> I've spent or wasted way too much time on this, I can't quit.

What is the name of the logical fallacy or cognitive bias in the above statement.

[I'm not sure if this is actually the right forum to ask this. I'm sorry if I'm in the wrong here]

Comment: It's the same fallacy that's involved in continuing a bad investment; economists have a term for it -- "sunk capital" or something like, I think.. The metaphor theme involved is [_`Time` Is `Money`_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), which accounts for the _spent time_. Normally all we can _spend_ is money, but the metaphor theme covers perceived duration as well. Is a metaphor theme considered a cognitive bias?

Comment: Thanks. Sunk Cost Fallacy is the formal name. That's what I was looking for. I couldn't remember the exact name or the cognitive bias that keeps us making it.

Comment: As you say, Sunk Cost Fallacy is a *formal* name. In casual conversation people are more likely to talk about ***throwing good money after bad***.

Comment: It's sunk cost only if you can treat perception as cost. And [_cost_ has a rather complex meaning](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler, in this instance, the phenomenon or the fallacy is called "Sunk Cost". It describes the emotional investments we accumulate. The fallacy in this instance refers to our emotional perception of the time and effort we've spent. It's not completely literal. 

https://youarenotsosmart.com/2011/03/25/the-sunk-cost-fallacy/

Comment: No, it's not literal at all; it's a metaphor theme. Like [_`Up` Is `Good`/`Down` Is `Bad`_](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), which is also implicated in _Sunk_. But it's not a fallacy as such; just a viewpoint. For some things, like emotions and perceived duration, we don't have anything **but** metaphors, because there is no "literal" reality to refer to.

Comment: @John Lawler I'm not clear whether you meant to deny that "sunk cost" thinking is fallacious. The fallacy is not related to metaphorical language. The fallacy is in failing to see that the sunk cost is irrelevant to the real decision. In the example at the top of the question, the correct comparison is not that I've spent too much time on this to quit now; the correct comparison is whether future time spent is justified by the good it will do. We should not pursue a bad course just because we've set out on one.

Comment: @Chaim - Well put.  While it may not be a bad choice to continue whatever you're doing, like digging for oil just a little further down, giving your investment of time undue weight can be the fallacy.  If in fact no oil exists even 'further down there,' the fact that you already dug so far should carry no weight beyond the consideration to cut your losses.

Comment: Not refuting **Sunk Cost** but also see the **Gambler's Fallacy** and **Streetlight Effect** bias as possible underlying or contributing fallacies.

Comment: There's a phrase used to describe this situation: "We've gone too far to turn back now."

Answer (score 2):

The psychological/emotional tension surrounding the decision as to whether to keep investing time or money in an endeavour such as the one you describe is the [sunk cost dilemma](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sunk-cost-dilemma.asp):

> the emotional difficulty of deciding whether to proceed with or abandon a project when time and money have already been spent but the desired results have not been achieved. (Investopedia)

And the [sunk cost trap](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sunk-cost-trap.asp) is when, because of a reluctance to admit to a waste of time or money, one continues with an obviously fruitless or wasteful endeavour that will not lead to the desired or best outcome. There are some good example scenarios in [this thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/33277/can-these-examples-alleging-the-sunk-cost-fallacy-really-not-be-fallacies) in the Philosophy forum.

If you fall into the trap, you are "[throwing good money after bad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throw_good_money_after_bad)", which is to

> incur further loss in a hopeless attempt to recoup a previous loss (Oxford Dictionaries)

(See also [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186789/etymology-of-throw-good-money-after-bad) with some examples of early usage.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalation_of_commitment

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in the unspoken premise: There is no amount of time too large to spend, in relation to the expected goal. The next question is the importance of the goal. Buying a new car? Saving your own life?

Depending on the goal, the statement about "too much time" might or might not be defensible.